# C++ Multiple inheritance known if it "is a" class outside direct hierachy path

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I have the following hierarchy of classes

```
A
|-B   I
  |-C-|
```

A is class of the system; B and C are my own.

In the system there is also a function that returns a pointer to the instance of A.

I is a minimal class, that if possible doesn't even any members.

When I do

```
A* pA= A::GetInstance();
if(!pA)
    return;

I* pI= dynamic_cast<I*>(pA);
if(!pI)
    return;
```

and my Instance is a C, the dynamic_cast always fails! And if I do Watch to the pA variable and open the respective node, it displays a line with the I class, making me think it is castable! Strange! ...

So, after reading some info in the Internet, it seems the class I supposedly needs to have something virtual.

Things I tried:

- Change the cast to be a static_cast. It doesn't even compile! I turned back to the dynamic_cast!
- Add a virtual destructor to it with an empty body. dynamic_cast fails!
- Change that destructor to be a pure virtual. This doesn't even compile (Note: B and C class already had virtual destructors!)
- Removed that destructor and implemented a void Dumb() method with an empty body in the I class. The dynamic_cast fails again!
- Changed that method to be a pure virtual and in C add that void Dumb() method with an empty body. It is failing one more time!

Please, what can I do to know whether my pA "is an" I?

UPDATE: by popular request, I added some minimal code for the classes:

```
// class A is not mine, and it indirectly inherits
// public CObject and has a virtual destructor!

class B: public A
{
public:
  virtual ~B();

 // the code!
};

class I
{
};

class C: public B, I
{
public:
  virtual ~B();

 // the code!
};
```

Comment: So, `A` has virtual functions, `I` does not?

Comment: Can you post minimal code for the classs?

Comment: Can be minimized like this: Class POD; Class Virtual; Class Link:POD,Virtual;

Comment: This actually makes sense if you think about what the compiler's looking at: given an A* and `dynamic_cast<I*>`, what should the compiler do to decide how to get there?  Suppose you have other kinds of objects that also derive from both, say `struct D: X,I {};`

Comment: Does it make sense? I thought it would have all neccessary info, because it starts at `A`, which has virtual functions...

Comment: I don't see anything implying `A` has virtual functions.

Comment: And you're sure `A::GetInstance()` is really a pointer to `C`?

Comment: Please use typeid() and print out some members of the returned object for verification.

Comment: But it doesn't have the necessary info: it has no indication that there's a `C` in there anywhere -- and even if it has the `C` definition, it has no indication that `C` is the only possibility. Should it try `dynamic_cast<X*>` for every class X that derives from both `A` and `I`?

Comment: @aschepler: The destructor is virtual. And there are more virtual methods!

Comment: @aschepler: and the watch window says that it is a pointer to C! If i dynamic_cast it to a C pointer, the cast does not fail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A { public: virtual ~A() { } };
class B : public A { };
class I { };
class C : public B, public I { };

int main()
{
    C c;
    A* a = &c;
    if (dynamic_cast<I*>(a))
        std::printf("it's a C\n");
    else
        std::printf("it's not a C\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note the second `public` in `C`'s declaration.

Comment: Thnaks a LOT! The public word in the second inheritance was the key to solve this issue!

Answer (score 3):

```
class C: public B, I
{ //...
```

`I` is a private base class of `C`, since you didn't specify the access of `I`.  (Your `public` applies only to `B`.)  Therefore an object of type `C` is not in fact an `I`.  `dynamic_cast` can only follow public inheritance relationships.

You may get different results if you change that to:

```
class C: public B, public I
{ //...
```

Comment: private? I thought standard for `class` is `protected`?

Comment: @Deduplicator 11.2p2: "In the absence of an _access-specifier_ for a base class, `public` is assumed when the derived class is defined with the _class-key_ `struct` and `private` is assumed when the class is defined with the _class-key_ `class`."

Answer (score 1):

First cast it to `C`, then you know it **is** an `I`:

```
A* pA= A::GetInstance();
if(!pA)
    return;

if( C* pC = dynamic_cast<C*>(pA) ) {
    I* pI= dynamic_cast<I*>(pC);
    if(!pI) return; // unnecessary, but you can keep it
    .
    .
    .
    /// do your thing with pI here
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: I find that strange. Is it conforming?

Comment: Not necessary.  A single `dynamic_cast` can find "cousin" base classes.

Comment: @asch: The questioner said it didn't work, even though even after going to the standard, it should AFAICT.